# How to make a line break using node.js and express-messages (\n isn't working)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm using node.js with exppres and I'm trying to send a flash message from the server with 'express-messages'. Everything is working well but I don't know how to send a flash message with line breaking. I was trying to put \n and \r\n and the end of the line but nothing happened.

This is the party of my code:

```
req.flash('success', 'Yes !\n\n' +
            'Your strength has increased by ' + newStrength + '.\n\n' + 
            'Your tolerance has increased by ' + newTolerance + '.\n\n' + 
            'Your charisma has increased by ' + newCharisma + '.\n\n' + 
            'Your intelligence has increased by ' + newIntelligence + '.\n\n' + 
            'You have gained ' + newCash + '$\n\n');
```

The response that I get is in one line and I really couldn't find the answer anywhere.

Comment: `<br>` ? Just guessing...

Comment: Unfortunately no, already tried